# Can an app created using Microsoft Desktop App converter be used on a Surface Hub?

Tags: desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I've converted an app using Microsoft's Desktop App Converter [Here are the instructions I followed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) and I was able to install it just fine on a laptop running Windows 10. I then used Windows Configuration Designer to create a package to use to install it on the Surface Hub, but that fails to install on the Surface Hub. It says a 'Provisioning failure occurred".

I've tried converting multiple apps and none of them install on the Hub. Am I doing something wrong or does the Desktop App Converter just not work with the Surface Hub?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install the app on the other devices, **for now**. It can run only on Windows 10 desktops (including the new Windows 10 S), not tablets (*ARM based*), phones, the Surface Hub or any other device from the Windows 10 ecosystem.

As the picture below shows, the Desktop Bridge is here to help you start migrating your app to a **full universal version**. Remember, you're still building your binaries as Win32/.NET resources, the only difference is that the Desktop Bridge helps you package them inside of an AppX instead of an MSI and allows you to **access the UWP APIs** (*live tiles, etc..,*), and of course get published in the **Windows Store**.

You can read more about the [Desktop Bridge migration process and options](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/15/the-path-from-a-desktop-app-to-a-universal-windows-platform-uwp-app/#AgRRXfp5u1WvTVYu.97) on the Microsoft blogs.

Once you get to the final step, *Reach All* from the below picture, where the code from your app is all UWP, you can deploy your application on any Windows 10 device you want.

[image]

Comment: Yes,`Surface Hub only runs Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps. Apps created using the Desktop App Converter will not run on Surface Hub. See a list of apps that work with Surface Hub`,check [official  document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/install-apps-on-surface-hub).